# FullCalendar json error

Tags: json, asmx, fullcalendar

I've been trying to figure this out for over a day now.  I have FullCalendar installed (v1.5.1) and i'm working with AgendaWeek.  I have asp.net v.3.5 installed and I"m trying to populate the calendar with events from a Json feed but it's not working.  Here is my code and errors.  If anybody can help, that would be great.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        //$(".myClass").css("border", "3px solid red");


        /* initialize the Web Service  
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
        $(".external-events").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "StudiesWebService.asmx/Return_Available_Codes",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                var c = eval(data.d);

                for (var i in c) {
                    $(".external-events").append(c[i]);
                };

            },
            error: function(e) { $(".external-events").html("An Error Occured" + e); }
        });

        /* end of web service call
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/



        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });

        /* end of initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/



        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: '',
                right: ''

            },
            eventSources: [

            // your event source
    {
    url: 'StudiesWebService.asmx/EventList',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: function() {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    },
    color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
    textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
}

            // any other sources...

     ],
            date: 17, //starting date.
            contentHeight: 780, //height of the calendar
            defaultEventMinutes: 60, //each droppable event is set to 60 min.
            slotMinutes: 15, //slot time interval
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek', //view to agenda week
            minTime: 6, //start time
            maxTime: 21, //end time
            allDaySlot: true,
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped


                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }

            }

        });

        //End of Calendar

    });

</script>
```

> Web Service:

```
 [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public string EventList(double start, double end)
{
     var list = new List<string>();
     list.Add("[{\"id\":\"36\"title\":\"Birthday party\",\"start\":\"2011-10-18 07:30\",\"end\":\"2011-10-18 10:30\",\"allDay\":false}]");

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = jss.Serialize(list.ToArray());
    return strJSON;




}
```

**Firebug Data and Errors**

Header:

Response Headersview source
Date    Thu, 20 Oct 2011 13:56:52 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer    5.0_Pub
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
jsonerror   true
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length  1063
Request Headersview source
Host    anessrv
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://anessrv/fullcalendar/default6.aspx
Content-Length  31
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache

Post:

Source
start=1318737600&end=1319342400

Response:

{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: start.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the anonymous object syntax.. I always find directly JSON strings to be a source of many bugs.  I'm not at my work computer right now to test this, but something like this will definitely serialize to JSON without errors, I just build a whole fullcalendar project around it. :)

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public string EventList(double start, double end)
{
    List<object> eventList = new List();

    eventList.Add(
        new {
            id = 36,
            title = "Birthday party",
            start = "2011-10-18 07:30",
            end = "2011-10-18 10:30",
            allDay = "false"
        }
    );

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = jss.Serialize(eventList);
    return strJSON;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like an answer to the problem show to me. The problem causing the exception is that the ASP.NET web service is seeing the contentType and trying to parse the Full Calendar "start" and "end" parameters accordingly... it then barfs because they're not valid. That's what it means by:
  "Invalid JSON primitive: start."

It's barfing on the first of the two parameters. The C# is your second problem, but you'll not get to it unless ASP.NET can pase the incoming request.

(1) To solve the issue in the question you need something like [this](http://blog.aardvarksoft.co.uk/index.php/2012/07/16/getting-fullcalendar-to-play-nicely-with-net-web-services/), which describes a couple of simple hacks you need to do to the FullCalendar JS. The first correctly formats the **data** parameter for jQuery Ajax:

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

That, and nothing much else, will get you past the error in the question and will allow your C# to run.

(2) At that point the above answer's C# should run, although there are lots of neater ways to skin that cat. But you still won't see your events on the calendar.

(3) That's because you're using ASP.NET and so you have a JSON response which you need to parse differently from the way the current version of fullcalendar does it. It is assuming you have an array of events in "events", but actually you've some JSON in events.d. Take a look in the debugger to see that. So what you need is (actually not what's shown in [1](http://blog.aardvarksoft.co.uk/index.php/2012/07/16/getting-fullcalendar-to-play-nicely-with-net-web-services/), which may be out of date), but:

```
events = $.parseJSON(events.d);
```

Then everything should drop into place. So you're three fixes from having it running. This I know because I just did it.